# Create view and use it in a single SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssms

Simple thing ... i thought. Create a view and use it later in the same SQL script.
Let's say we have a script as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW someView AS (...)
DROP VIEW someView
```

If I try to parse it SQL Management complaints there's an error around DROP.
If I execute them separately (create first, then drop) they work both fine.
Is there any way to create a view and use it in a single SQL script?
I could wrap further statements in string an then EXEC it but it's a bit inconvenient.

**Code example was fixed (missing VIEW)**

More meaningful example:

```
create view TEST as (select name from spt_values where number=1);
drop view TEST
```

Is it possible to execute it at once? 
I got the error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TEST, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'drop'.
```

Running create statement separately and then dropping view works perfectly.

Comment: SQLServer 2005 + Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 9.00.5000.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate your query with `GO` keyword like query bellow:

```
CREATE VIEW someView AS ()
GO

DROP VIEW someView
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of which particular DBMS you are using, you should create a script separating your SQL statements with ';'.

For example

```
CREATE VIEW someView as (...);

<<some other sql statements>>

DROP VIEW someView;
```

Comment: That's right, nonetheless it does not solve the problem - how to use newly created view later, within the same script.

Comment: Please post more of your script and the error you are getting.

Comment: create view TEST as (select name from spt_values where number=1);
    drop view TEST

Comment: Please always update your original question so that the entire problem statement is in one place.